# Wrong return from R.string using Robotium .getString() method

Tags: android, robotium

I try to get Android settings from R.string using Robotium

```
String loginButton = solo.getString(test_project_package.R.string.login_button);
```

string.xml file contain (located in the test project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="login_button">Sign In to App.</string>
</resources>
```

Problem is in the returning value. Instead of **"Sign In to App."**, Java return **"res/layout/bottom.xml"**. It seems that it is a path from source code of app. that is in the same workspace).

I tried not to use solo:

```
Resources resources = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();
String loginButton = res.getString(test_project_package.R.string.login_button);
```

Same problem.

What is wrong? Why Java returns an incorrect value?

Comment: There are some issues with rebuilding the R class when you only change an xml file. Have you tried cleaning the projects (all of them)?

Comment: I select Project - Clean... - Clean all projects in Eclipse 4.2.1. Same results

Answer (score 1):

Partially solved this problem :)

Add the following import in the test project:

```
import project_package.R;
```

After that it is possible to use settings from source code. Java returns right parameters.

```
solo.clickOnButton(solo.getString(R.string.add_account_button));
```

**But!** If you want to get parameters from test project and set import like this:

```
import project_package.test.R;
```

or just without import Java will return wrong parameter. Don't know why

I found this tip in article [Android Testing with the Android Test framework, Robotium, Monkey and Robolectric](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTesting/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think `solo.getString()` is not to fetch the strings from String.xml
It is to get the strings associated with the views in current activity.

To get the strings from String.xml use the following :

```
solo.getContext().getString( resId );
```

in your case -

```
solo.getContext().getString( R.string.login_button );
```

should work fine.